# Pass Listbox Items as array to another pages

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am making an app in VS2012 c# for Windows 8.
I have one listbox 'a' and i want to pass its items to another page 'Pageone.xaml'.
This listbox item will contain both numbers and characters.

P.S. :
Can we make this listbox global(i.e. it can be used by all pages)

Answer (score 0):

You could be using a `ViewModel` for this. Check out something like [MvvmLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com). You create an IOC and Service Locator (well, the template will create one for you) which allows you to access your `ViewModel`s from anywhere in your app via `Source={StaticResource Locator}`.